# How to make a higher-order function to process other functions and make them useable by a recursive `while` function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

So I have these functions:

```
/**
 * @description Recurses while a condition is true. Not stack-safe.
 * @param {Object} object_arguments - Contains the arguments for the function.
 * @param {function} object_arguments.object_function - The function to execute.
 * @param {any[]} object_arguments.array_arguments - The arguments to pass to the function.
 * @param {boolean} object_arguments.boolean_condition - The condition that must be met for another recursion to occur.
 * @returns {any} The output after all the recursions.
 */
const any_while = ({
  object_function: f,
  array_arguments: a,
  boolean_condition: c,
}) => {
  if (c) {
    const object_output = f(...a);
    return any_while({
      object_function: object_output.object_function,
      array_arguments: object_output.array_arguments,
      boolean_condition: object_output.boolean_condition,
    });
  } else {
    return f(...a).any_output;
  }
};
```

and

```
const integer_increment = (integer) => integer + 1;
```

I want another function, let's call it `function_convert_for_while`, that takes in any function, in this case `integer_increment`, and outputs another function that can be used as the `object_function` parameter by the `any_while` function, and also would probably have to take in some other arguments to set conditions. So the function outputted by `function_convert_for_while` should output an object with the shape:

```
{
  object_function,
  array_arguments,
  boolean_condition,
  any_output
}
```

Where `object_function` is the "converted" function, "array_arguments" contains the arguments for the converted function in the next recursion of `any_while`, `boolean_condition` is the stop/go condition, and `any_output` is the final output after all the recursions.

I'm having trouble envisioning how `function_convert_for_while` should be though, and especially how it'd handle the `boolean_condition` variable since that's supposed to change according to the value of `any_output` after every recursion. I'm thinking maybe I'd need another function for that which takes in the `any_output` variable and makes some sort of comparison? But I'm not too sure about it. Sorry if this is all a bit incoherent, let me know if I should explain anything a bit better, and if there's better ways to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve. I'd really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: That `any_while` is pretty weird, I wouldn't use it. I would suggest to start over, and first write out a few of the `while` loops that you want to abstract from. Then look what bits are different between the loops.

Comment: @Bergi Hi, thanks for the advice. I'm not sure if this is correct, but I guess the bits that were different are the state outside the loop, the computations inside the loop that changes the state, and the conditions based on that state that tell the loop to continue or stop. How might you suggest I write the `any_while` function instead of how it currently is?

Comment: Yes. The standard approach to a functional `while` is then a function that takes 1. the initial state 2. a function that computes one step (takes state, returns new state) and 3. a predicate function (takes state) that returns true while it should continue.

Comment: @Bergi Apparently a more direct translation of a while loop would be something like: `const any_while = ({ boolean_condition, any_state, any_function, }) => boolean_condition(any_state) ? any_while({ boolean_condition: boolean_condition, any_state: any_function(any_state), any_function: any_function, }) : any_state;`, In which `boolean_condition` and `any_function` can never change. Out of curiosity though, is there anything "bad" about the `any_while` in my original post? Why did you think it was weird?

Comment: Yes, precisely. There is an alternative formulation where a function returns a new function (working similar to an iterator, or rather being simply a [trampolined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) recursive function), but you shouldn't mix these two approaches.

Comment: Apart from not being "the normal" formulation, I found it weird that the `array_arguments` were part of the object, which is unnecessary if you're already creating a different `object_function` for each iteration, and the base case where the `object_function` is still called another time when the boolean is already `false`.

Comment: @Bergi Ah ok, fair enough. Regarding this alternative formulation you speak of, I've not come across it before, please could you link me to some resources so that I can learn more about it?

Comment: I don't know any resources or whether it even has a name, I guess being a trampoline will come closest. It would be something like `function run(val) { return val.done ? val.result : run(val.next()); }` or (with always at least one call, similar to do-while) `function run(f) { const val = f(); return val.done ? val.result : run(val.next); }`.